# How do I get my ActionBar Items to show as icons, and not in the overflow menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

First off, I'm running the latest Lollipop - Minimum and targeted SDK are both 22

```
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 22
```

in the gradle build. I've changed/re changed these to 22, as well as rebuilt/invalidated caches/cleaned. I'm extending Activity in my main:

```
public class login_activity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}
}
```

And here are my menu items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/login_help"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
    android:title="@string/login_help_text"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

When I run my code, it keeps showing the items in the ActionBar overflow menu. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "**ifroom**" with "**always**" for **showAsAction** like below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/login_help"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
    android:title="@string/login_help_text"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Hey, I posted my complete answer down below, could you please point to that or something because this solution will not work if your gradle files are outdated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually spent nearly five hours trying to figure this out, but I actually figured it out just now going through my gradle files. Here's how you fix it:

- Go to your Gradle Scripts folder
- Open the build.gradle file with the SDK options in it
- Remove the line under dependencies (Mine's this one, not sure how they vary):

  ```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' (REMOVE THIS)
  ```
- Go back to your menu file and REMOVE the namespace definition for the namespace you put before showAsAction

  ```
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" (REMOVE THIS)
  ```
- Go change the showAsAction line from something:showAsAction to android:showAsAction

Rebuild & compile. It should work! I wish changing the SDK cleaned up after itself, but hey, what can you do.